# "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable

Tags: java, multithreading, mongodb, apache-spark, serialization

I'm trying to run the following simple Spark code:

```
public static void main(final String[] args)throws Exception {

    ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getClass().getName();
    Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getClass().getName();
    GraphApiApplication.class.getClassLoader();

    /*if (args.length < 1) {
        System.err.println("try again");
        System.exit(1);
    }*/

    GraphApiApplication main = new GraphApiApplication();
    main.run();
}

private void run(){
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .master("spark://192.168.xx.xx:7077")
            .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://192.168.xx.xx:27017/database.test_spark")
            .config("spark.database.output.uri", "mongodb://192.168.xx.xx:27017/database.test_spark")
            .config("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
            .appName("SparkTest")
            .getOrCreate();

    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());

    // Create a custom WriteConfig
    Map<String, String> writeOverrides = new HashMap<String, String>();
    writeOverrides.put("collection", "spark");
    writeOverrides.put("writeConcern.w", "majority");
    WriteConfig writeConfig = WriteConfig.create(jsc).withOptions(writeOverrides);

    // Create a RDD of 10 documents
    JavaRDD<Document> sparkDocuments = jsc.parallelize(asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)).map
        (new Function<Integer, Document>() {
            public Document call(final Integer i) throws Exception {
                return Document.parse("{spark: " + i + "}");
            }
        });

    System.out.println("collection : "+writeOverrides);
    MongoSpark.save(sparkDocuments, writeConfig);
    spark.stop();
}
```

Log Exception here :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2094)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:370)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:369)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:369)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.map(JavaRDDLike.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.map(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
    at com.bdg.ebdesk.graph_api.GraphApiApplication.run(GraphApiApplication.java:60)
    at com.bdg.ebdesk.graph_api.GraphApiApplication.main(GraphApiApplication.java:37)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.bdg.ebdesk.graph_api.GraphApiApplication
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: com.bdg.ebdesk.graph_api.GraphApiApplication, value: com.bdg.ebdesk.graph_api.GraphApiApplication@7e0aadd0)
    - field (class: com.bdg.ebdesk.graph_api.GraphApiApplication$1, name: this$0, type: class com.bdg.ebdesk.graph_api.GraphApiApplication)
    - object (class com.bdg.ebdesk.graph_api.GraphApiApplication$1, com.bdg.ebdesk.graph_api.GraphApiApplication$1@62d363ab)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1, name: fun$1, type: interface org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1, <function1>)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:295)
    ... 13more
```

Here 'jsc' is the JavaSparkContext object I'm using. As far as I know, JavaSparkContext is not a Serializable object and one should not use it inside any functions which will be sent to the Spark workers.

Now, what I'm not able to understand is, how the instance of JavaSparkContext is being sent to the workers? What should I change in my code to avoid such scenario?

Answer (score 1):

When you are writing anonymous inner class, named inner class or lambda, Java creates reference to the outer class in  the inner class.

So even if the inner class is serializable, the exception can occur, the outer class must be also serializable.

Add `implements Serializable` to your class GraphApiApplication, because this if the outer class for anonymous inner class that is written as argument in map function

Comment: @AnwarHuda Also all fields must be Serializable